# Redshift copy just aborts after 5 hours when copying lots of files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to upload all my logs ( around 2000 files ) onto redshift using a single copy command. CPU spikes to 50% and keeps running for 5 hours and then just stops. No errors shown on redshift AWS console; No errors in stl_load_errors also. Percentage disk usage was shooting up from 2% to 30%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasted so many days in this. Finally could solve this problem by dividing number of log files in smaller chunks.. each chunk having around 50 files..Percentage disk space also did not shoot .. even after full load only 10% disk usage happened.